# Duplicate Table Definition (columns) in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a quick and easy way to duplicate a table in SQL-Server?  I just want to make a temporary table from table A because I need to refresh table B (which will interfere with the foreign keys).

I know this isn't a ridiculous task to do manually, but it seems like there should be a nice way to do it.

Edit:  To clarify, I want to duplicate the table *definition*, not the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be a better approach to just temporarily disable constraints while you are doing your *refresh*

```
 ALTER TABLE X NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
 -- Refresh SQL 
 ALTER TABLE X CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Comment: I thought about that briefly, but it makes me a bit nervous to actually mess with the real databse's definition like that...  Actually, if you're only disabling the constraints, that's pretty nice.  I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Personally I find this approach to be least messy.

Comment: This is actually the best for my situation.  It's simple and also feels safer since I'm not actually moving any data or deleting/truncating anything.

Comment: Note:  Truncate Table will not work with this, but Delete From will.

Answer (score 6):

Try this?

```
SELECT
  *
INTO
  #temp
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  1=0
```

It won't duplicate constraints, indexes, etc.  But it should duplicate the data-types and field names.

Comment: If I may ask, what is the Where 1 = 0 for?  It seems to work without it.

Comment: Should keep the data from copying into it, which is what you wanted via your edit

Comment: Correct, you said you don't want to copy the table contents.  1 never equals 0, so no records will come through.  But the #temp table will still be created with the required definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TableB
( SELECT * FROM TableA )
```

Comment: This will copy the data into an existing TableB from TableA.  What the OP is looking for is to copy the *definition* of the table over.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table_name [IN externaldatabase]
FROM old_tablename
```

W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213050%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

SELECT INTO can be used to combine data from several tables or views into one table. It can also be used to create a new table containing data selected from a linked server.

Answer (score 0):

select * into copyTable from sourceTable